# Optimized mysql table schema for reading and writing data

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, schema

I am working on a project which has a requirement of storing data in mysql coming to a server from multiple tracking devices. The data interval is 10s.

Currently the way we store data is as follows:

Each device has a single table ({Device_Number}_info) with Unix Timestamp as primary key. (So if we have 10,000 devices, we end up in 10,000 tables. This is done to prevent locking since we insert into the table every 10s).

Data every 10s is inserted into the respective tables and later accessed.

The problem with this approach is, If we have to get a single row for each device - we have to loop over all 10,000 tables and execute a query. We tried all possible ways to optimize queries and add indexes to the table, but nothing works. Looping over all tables and executing a query takes time. Our goal is to get the rows in <10s. I feel that there is something which can be improved using mysql optimization techniques.

What we tried :

We created a single view of all 10,000 tables (taking union). Then queried the view. This did not work either. It takes more than 2 minutes.

Any suggestions on how we can design the schema for optimized read and writes?

Here is the schema of {device_number}_info table :

```
{device_number}_info:
  device_number int(11) NOT NULL,
  Date date NOT NULL,
  Time time NOT NULL,
  Timestamp int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  Speed float NOT NULL,
  Latitude double NOT NULL,
  Longitude double NOT NULL,
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Why don't you use just one table? 1000 inserts/sec should not be an issue, inserts do not lock whole table.

Comment: We tried using a single table too, querying becomes a bottleneck when the data reaches more than lakhs. Queries are just too slow at that time!

Comment: Selecting from a table having hundreds of thousands (had to google it:-) ) of rows shouldn't be an issue. Perhaps you are not indexing properly? Can you post an example of a SELECT?

Comment: Thanks. But indexing slows down the inserts right? In "where" clause of the queries we almost have all the fields from the table. Do you suggest indexing all fields?

Comment: Yes, indexing slows down the inserts. You do not have to have indexes on ALL the columns you have in WHERE clause. At least one of the columns in the where clause should be indexed, or you are doing a full table scan (expensive). The docs explain how indexes are used: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try. (It took 0.4 seconds to fetch a single row from 3,00,000 rows. It increases with number of rows with old design. )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153232/discussion-between-honza-zika-and-sumeet-jain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in a separate discussion:

- merge all tables to one master table
- use indexed column (`Timestamp`) in the `where` part of the query to greatly increase speed
- increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to reduce disk IO time

Answer (score 1):

Are the "devices" moving?  If not, don't include lat/lng in the table.  Ditto for any other unchanging values.

Do have a single table.

Do have `PRIMARY KEY(device_id, timestamp)` -- in this order.  Note that this will separate the inserts into separate parts of the table.

Do not (without good reason) repeat the `timestamp` in `date` and `time`.  In most situations, you can dynamically convert.

`DOUBLE` is overkill for lat/lng.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) for smaller options.

Shrinking the table size will improve performance.

When inserting 1000 rows per second, batch them up and do them either with a single `LOAD DATA` or a single, multi-row, `INSERT`.  It will take some time, but it should be much less than 10 seconds (the drop-dead limit) except on a 'cold' system.

`device_number` can be `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes instead of 4; limit of 16M - 1.6 crore).

If you are fetching data for all devices for a given time, you will need a secondary `INDEX(timestamp)`.

Keep in mind that more indexes means slower `INSERTs`, so please provide all the indexes you think you need, together with the query that they were designed for.  We should discuss them.

How long do you keep the data?  It sounds like 30 billion rows a year?  If you are purging, then the `DELETE` becomes a serious issue.  We can discuss that.

How much RAM?  HDD or SSD drive?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will definitely try these out.